# Numba automatically simplify and skip codes?

Tags: python, numba

I installed the latest Python, Numba and CUDA CDK version 10 where I found the following result to be really interesting:

Code I:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit
import math as ma

start = timer()
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def test5():

    for i in range(1,100000000):
        for j in range(1,10000000):
            for h in range(1,100000000):
                for z in range(1,10000000):
                    for h1 in range(1,100000000):
                        for z1 in range(1,10000000):
                             ma.exp(ma.log(i));
                             i**i;

test5()


duration = timer() - start
print(duration)
```

The run time, was the unrealistic 0.166942700000007 s!

Code II:

```
start = timer()
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def test5():

    for i in range(1,100000000):
        for j in range(1,100):
            i**i;
            if i==10000000*j:
                print(i)


test5()


duration = timer() - start
print(duration)
```

The run time was 3.934219299999995 s

How could that be?

My conclusion is that, in code block I, the code did not run at all!
Because the code was not used nor being sent as the output, so @jit automatically simplified and skipped all the unnecessary code.

My questions are:

1. What's going on with code I? Why it's so unrealistic faster? or why the code II was so much slower?
2. How to tell Numba to run all the code without skip any of the necessary code?

Comment: You don't measure the runtime, but compilation+runtime. Call the function once before the timing to get the runtime. Yes Numba does a dead code elimination (There is no necessary code in Example I) https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/architecture.html

Comment: @max9111 Thank you! So is there a way to get away with dead code elimination? I mean run the dead code no matter what. I mean sometimes I need to use this function purely to test which algorithm or process is faster.

Comment: @JC There are better ways for profiling than writing dead code blocks. Why not just return one variable of the dead code block or assign it to the view of some input array? This is more realisic, since you most probably will use the results of the code that you want to profile.